# ASP.NET and MySQL .Net Framework Data Provider Issues

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I'm new in ASP.NET. Everytime I try to run my application, I encounter the error message below. I already installed .Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL several times.
I hope someone can help me on this. Thanks in advance.

```
Server Error in '/PLDT QuickSearcher' Application.

Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
```

Comment: Did you configure '<system.data>' in your web.config file?

Comment: Are you trying to run your application on a remote server? Try putting the mysql provider DLL into the same folder as the .dll, the /bin folder.

Comment: Have you added the dll as a reference to the project ?

Comment: I'm just testing it on my local PC. I added DLL reference and also added <system.data> on web.config but still getting the same error message. It was working before i format my PC. Is it possible it is not working because MySQL is not installed properly?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add MySql.Data.dll as reference to the project
Add this block to web.config:

```html
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory,MySql.Data" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But i still getting the same error message.

Comment: @SiHyungLee did you uninstall the connector or the actual server? Did you run a new version?

Answer (score 10):

Reference the MySql.Data and MySql.Entities Nuget packages.  Then add this line to your web config.

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Your connection string should be similar to the following:

```
<add name="MyDb" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=MyDb;Uid=root;Pwd=;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Comment: That top-section is really finicky.  I tried a bunch of other flavors of that I found on the web, but using yours verbatim worked for me.  (fortunately I'm already on the same version, 6.5.4.0)

Comment: Make sure you're writting the correct version of the assembly. Currently 6.6.4.0

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem with following configuration

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
             invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
             description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
             type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

  <entityFramework>  
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
                  type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```